# How can I set Dateformat dd/MM/yyyy using jDATECHOOSER

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdatechooser

I´m trying to get/set following Date Format into the Database(MySQL) dd/MM/yyyy.

In the DB, the column "Geburt" is set as DATE and is already known that the standard format from MySQL is yyyy/MM/dd.

Added to it, I´m using jDateChooser for selecting, inserting and updating data.

It looks like this now:

```
 private void wiwTextFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                  
    String userId = wiwText.getText();

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_TEILNEHMER WHERE WIW= ?";
        S**tring dateValue = rs.getString("Geburt"); // What ever column
        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateValue);** //I added this here from a example I saw here
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,userId);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            nameText.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
            vornameText.setText(rs.getString("Vorname"));
            geburtChooser.setDate(date);
            mailText.setText(rs.getString("Mail"));
            telText.setText(rs.getString("Telefon"));
            reText.setText(rs.getString("re"));
            dcText.setText(rs.getString("dc"));
            emeaText.setText(rs.getString("emea"));
            assetText.setText(rs.getString("assetid"));
            modellCombo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("Model"));
            herstellerText.setText(rs.getString("hersteller"));
            strasseText.setText(rs.getString("strasse"));
            nummerText.setText(rs.getString("nummers"));
            stadtText.setText(rs.getString("stadt"));
            privatnummerText.setText(rs.getString("privatnummer"));
            privatmailText.setText(rs.getString("privatmail"));
            handyText.setText(rs.getString("handy"));
            whatsCombo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("whats"));
            skypeText.setText(rs.getString("skype"));
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

        }else{
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Benutzer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I´ve tried to find my answer here and on StackOverFlow from Brazil, but not found.

With this method I was trying to update the data I got into the select.
None of both ways worked.

```
 private void bearbeitenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try{
        String sql = "UPDATE TBL_TEILNEHMER SET NAME=?, VORNAME=?, GEBURT=?, MAIL=?, TELEFON=?, RE=?, DC=?, EMEA=?, ASSETID=?, MODEL=?, HERSTELLER=?, "
                + "STRASSE=?, NUMMERS=?, STADT=?, PRIVATNUMMER=?, PRIVATMAIL=?, HANDY=?, WHATS=?, SKYPE=? WHERE WIW='"+wiwText.getText()+"'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, nameText.getText());
        pst.setString(2, vornameText.getText());
        pst.setString(3, geburtChooser.getDate().toString());
        pst.setString(4, mailText.getText());
        pst.setString(5, telText.getText());
        pst.setString(6, reText.getText());
        pst.setString(7, dcText.getText());
        pst.setString(8, emeaText.getText());
        pst.setString(9, assetText.getText());
        pst.setString(10, modellCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(11, herstellerText.getText());
        pst.setString(12, strasseText.getText());
        pst.setString(13, nummerText.getText());
        pst.setString(14, stadtText.getText());
        pst.setString(15, privatnummerText.getText());
        pst.setString(16, privatmailText.getText());
        pst.setString(17, handyText.getText());
        pst.setString(18, whatsCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(19, skypeText.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Benutzerdaten wurden bearbeitet.");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Could someone help me?

My problem is basically I can´t convert the format from MySQL to the Format of datechooser although I´ve already changed the format in datechooser to yyyy.MM.dd ...

I´m doing something really wrong. I´ve tried many ways and nothing worked.
Also tried to change the DateFormat in MySQL ... reached nothing.

THANK YOU!

Comment: See SimpleDateFormat (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Don't change the dateformat in the chooser - this should be in the format specific to the user's locale. Instead convert the date into the format you are expecting, then set that on the database. Likewise, convert the date back to the specific locale when you go to display it.

Comment: `String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObj); pst.setString(3, dateString)`   .. an example. Almost 100% certain this question is a duplicate. ;)

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to get the date before you have executed the query? And you do not need a date format in a database - it's not saved as a string inside the database and you don't need to deal with the format if you use `setDate()` and `getDate()` properly in your JDBC calls.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah its not clear at all - there is more wrong here than just the way the dates are being handled. For one "Gebert" is supposedly DATE, but its set as a String. If I had to take a blind guess at what is wrong, its that the format going into the DB is different than the one coming out ... and yeah, that headache could be avoided with the proper JDBC calls :\

Comment: @trooper ... I´m still a noob. Ok. So this a good question... would you like to suggest some books ? I think my code could get cleaner and if I did something wrong it´s not a problem pointing it. I like when people try to help me but helping it´s not even just showing the code, I want to learn the right form too. It would be nice if you can suggest smth. I´m trying "Clean Code" and "Java- How to program".

Comment: @BasilBourque before vote down you may read what someone wrote! It´s not the same question. With Datechooser it works not getTimeStamp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
pst.setString(4,((JTextField)geburtChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

Now it works!